# Setting Column Width with PHPExcel Not Working

Tags: php, phpexcel, xlsx

I am trying to format the cell widths of a document that I am creating with PHPExcel, yet when I use the getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(7) method, it is not being produced accurately in the generated xlsx file.

I formatted the document in Excel so that I could find the values of the cells that I want and I get two values, one in Excel Units and the other in Inches.

For example:

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth('7');
```

will end up giving me a column width of 6.17 instead of 7. I have already tried using both strings and int values for, nothing changes. Any ideas?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

This is because MS Excel adjusts the figure itself to its own internal units: there's a whole section in the developer documentation (section 4.6.28, entitled "Setting a column’s width") that explains this.

Quoting from the sidebar in that section:

> The measure for column width in PHPExcel does not correspond exactly
>   to the measure you may be used to in Microsoft Office Excel. Column
>   widths are difficult to deal with in Excel, and there are several
>   measures for the column width.
>
> 1. Inner width in character units (e.g. 8.43 this is probably what you are familiar with in Excel)
> 2. Full width in pixels (e.g. 64 pixels)
> 3. Full width in character units (e.g. 9.140625, value -1 indicates
>      unset width)
>
> PHPExcel always operates with 3) "Full width in character units" which
>   is in fact the only value that is stored in any Excel file, hence the
>   most reliable measure. **Unfortunately, Microsoft Office Excel does not
>   present you with this measure. Instead measures 1) and 2) are computed
>   by the application when the file is opened and these values are
>   presented in various dialogues and tool tips.**
>
> The character width unit is the width of a '0' (zero) glyph in the
>   workbooks default font. Therefore column widths measured in character
>   units in two different workbooks can only be compared if they have the
>   same default workbook font.
>
> If you have some Excel file and need to know the column widths in
>   measure 3), you can read the Excel file with PHPExcel and echo the
>   retrieved values.

(my emphasis in bold)

Answer (score 0):

Add 0.71 to the excel cell width value and give that value to the

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(10);
```

eg: A Column width = 3.71 (excel value)

give column width = 4.42

will give the output file with same cell width.

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(4.42);
```

Comment: Also before set with you need to disable auto size
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);

Answer (score 0):

Before set width of any column, first you need to disable auto size

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
```

After that, you need to set a width

```
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setWidth(40);
```

Calculation of width that I found in MS Excel:
MS Excel minus 0.71 from our defined size.
Example: When you define width 40 in code that MS Excel set width 39.29.
So good way to put an exact required size of any column, first you set a required width in MS Excel then adds 0.71 into that and set in your code.

After set width, you can again enable auto size.

Answer (score -4):

try this:-
add below line before setting width:-

```
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);
```