# PHPExcel setWidth() in cm

Tags: php, excel, phpexcel, xlsx

I got an enhancement task from client that they want to specific the width of each cell of the Excel file (Ms. Excel) in cm (e.g. column "Name" = 5cm).

I've tried to search for the solutions and got some suggestions like :

```
$excel->getActiveSheet()->getColumnDimension('A')->setAutoSize(false);
$excel->exa_setColumnWidth('A', [some_value]);
```

But sadly, `[some_value]` here is not in `cm`. And until now, I still have no idea what is that measure.

I also found this link [Setting Column Width with PHPExcel Not Working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14162013/setting-column-width-with-phpexcel-not-working) but it is told that it is impossible to do that. But somehow I want to try to ask, in case recently someone has any idea about how to achieve that.

Comment: default column width is apparently 8.43 chars of the default font(the font assinged to the normal style) fit into a cell. In excel, looking in: file/options/advanced/display you can change 'ruler units' to cm. Then select in workbook 'View' the 'page layout'. In the 'page layout' view you can right-click on a column header to select 'column width', which should now be in 'cm'. Now set the column width to 5cm and go back to 'normal' view. Check out the column width (right click a column and show column width) this should be the corresponding setting for [some value].

Comment: @jibsteroos : I changed the ruler units to "cm", then go to set the width in page layout to 5cm, but right 
after I click OK, after I entered 5cm, if I right-click and check the width again, it becomes 
4.97cm.

I know it's about Ms. Excel, but have you got any idea here?

Comment: Oh by the way, after I followed your instruction, after I set [some value] and go back to check the width in the Excel, it shows "4.84cm", it is supposed to be 5cm actually.  It might be because of that decrease I mentioned in the above comment.

Comment: checked the value should be 24.29 for 5cm